# Anyone able to install Drupal 8 Thunder (with Composer) on Pantheon?

Tags: composer-php, drupal-8, pantheon

I've been trying to get Drupal 8 Thunder running on Pantheon, but have hit some roadblocks.

I've got Thunder running locally following these instructions:
https://github.com/BurdaMagazinOrg/thunder-project/blob/2.x/README.md

The trying to use some of the directions for getting a Composer site up on Pantheon: https://pantheon.io/docs/guides/drupal-8-composer-no-ci/

I'm able to push code up (after deleting git submodules and creating a symlink for docroot), but get stuck at the installation step.

Cheers,
Kevin

Answer (score 1):

I figured out a (somewhat hacky) way to get this done, and stuck a composer.json file and instructions on GitHub:

https://github.com/kevcol/pantheon-thunder-8-composer